# Are there practical problems in optimization where its dual problem is computationally easier to solve?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

In a class I learned that optimization problems can have "dual counterparts"

For example, a problem of the type

$$\min_{x} f(x) + g(x)$$

has a "Fenchel" dual problem:

$$\max_{y} -f^\ast(y)  - g^\ast(-y)$$

As another example:

$$\min_{x} f_0(x) \text{ s.t. } f_i(x) \leq 0$$

has a "Lagrange" dual problem:

$$\max_{\lambda \geq 0} L(x, \lambda)$$
where $L$ is the Lagrangian.

There is some relationship of course between $x$ and $y$ or $\lambda$, which makes it possible to recover the optimizer.

> My question is: are there practical problems in optimization where
> duality is useful because it makes the original problem **easier to
> solve**?

I have seen some very contrived toy examples (for example, $\min x^3$ on x$ \in [3, 5]$) where it seems the dual problem is much harder to solve than the original problem.

Comment: The first example I can think of is SVM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine

Comment: This is being exploited by solvers all the time. For example 1) The dual of a linear problem transposes the $A$ matrix, which depending on the shape can reduce the sizes (the solver typically needs to compute either $AA^T$ or $A^TA$ a lot). 2) The dual problem may be much sparser than the original. Not only the solvers can dualize, but even modeling tools very typically dualize the user problem before calling the solver for these reasons.